# SOAP WSDL Uncaught exceptio [could not connect to host]

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to consume a web service using this call

```
try{
                ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled","0");
                ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache","0");
                ini_set("display_errors","On");
                ini_set("track_errors","On");
//                libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);

                $opts = array(
                    'ssl' => array('ciphers'=>'RC4-SHA', 'verify_peer'=>false, 'verify_peer_name'=>false),
                    'http' => array("header" => "User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.3\r\n")
                );
                // SOAP 1.1 client
                $params = array (
                    'trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => true, "connection_timeout" => 300,
                    );
                $client = new SoapClient("http://duffystaxi.no-ip.info:6928/XDS_IASPI.DLL/wsdl/IWebAccount3", $params);



}catch(SoapFault $e){
                echo "ERROR!!! Please check your internet connection and try again, contact webmaster if error persists";
                echo "<pre>";
                var_dump(libxml_get_last_error());
                var_dump($e);
                echo "<p>".$e->getTraceAsString()."</p>";
                echo "<p>".$e->getMessage()."</p>";

                echo "</pre>";
                die();
//                echo "Error!";
//                echo $e -> getMessage ();
//                echo 'Last response: '. $this->client->__getLastResponse();
}
```

it works just fine on my local server, but returns a **FATAL ERROR** on production. I saw a suggestion from thorough search to save the file and call it locally, which did work on local server as well but not on production(called it on production server using "http://example.com/wsdl/abc.wsdl").
The WSDL looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="IWebAccount3service" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:ns1="urn:TypeAccount" xmlns:ns2="urn:TypeWEB" xmlns:ns3="urn:TypeOrder" xmlns:ns4="urn:StaticDataIntf">
  <types>
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="urn:TypeAccount" xmlns="urn:TypeAccount">
      <xs:complexType name="TBookAccount">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="ServiceProviderID" type="xs:int"/>
          <xs:element name="AccountID" type="xs:int"/>
          <xs:element name="AccType" type="ns2:TAccountType"/>
          <xs:element name="WEBStatus" type="ns2:TWEBAccountStatus"/>
          <xs:element name="WEBID" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="WEBPassword" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="AccountName" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="LastName" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="Phone" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="Fax" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="eMail" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="Address" type="ns3:TWEBAddress"/>
          <xs:element name="CCNumber" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="CCHolder" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="CCStartMonth" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="CCStartYear" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="CCEndMonth" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="CCEndYear" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="CCSecurityCode" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="CCIssueNumber" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="TBookAccount2">
        <xs:complexContent>
          <xs:extension base="ns1:TBookAccount">
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="OwnerID" type="xs:int"/>
              <xs:element name="OwnerType" type="xs:int"/>
              <xs:element name="TextBack" type="xs:boolean"/>
              <xs:element name="EmailBack" type="xs:boolean"/>
              <xs:element name="CallBack" type="xs:boolean"/>
              <xs:element name="AccountAdmin" type="xs:boolean"/>
              <xs:element name="Priority" type="xs:boolean"/>
              <xs:element name="Email2" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="MobilePhone" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="BusinessType" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="UserPosition" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="TripRemark" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="AdminNotes" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="LPoints" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="BarCode" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="DeptName" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="DriverRating" type="xs:int"/>
              <xs:element name="CallbackPhone" type="xs:int"/>
              <xs:element name="EMailbackAddress" type="xs:int"/>
              <xs:element name="Prompt1" type="ns1:TPromptField"/>
              <xs:element name="Prompt2" type="ns1:TPromptField"/>
              <xs:element name="Prompt3" type="ns1:TPromptField"/>
              <xs:element name="Prompt4" type="ns1:TPromptField"/>
              <xs:element name="Prompt5" type="ns1:TPromptField"/>
              <xs:element name="Prompt6" type="ns1:TPromptField"/>
              <xs:element name="Prompt7" type="ns1:TPromptField"/>
              <xs:element name="Prompt8" type="ns1:TPromptField"/>
              <xs:element name="FavoriteAddresses" type="ns1:TFavoriteAddressesArray"/>
              <xs:element name="Exceptions" type="ns3:TExceptionsArray"/>
              <xs:element name="VehicleTypes" type="ns4:TVehicleTypeArray"/>
              <xs:element name="WebReservation" type="xs:boolean"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="TPromptField">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="FieldID" type="xs:int"/>
          <xs:element name="Caption" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="Required" type="xs:boolean"/>
          <xs:element name="Search" type="xs:boolean"/>
          <xs:element name="HasPassword" type="xs:boolean"/>
          <xs:element name="DefaultValue" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="ValueList" type="ns1:TPromptValueArray"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="TPromptValueArray">
        <xs:complexContent>
          <xs:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
            <xs:sequence/>
            <xs:attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" n1:arrayType="xs:string[]" xmlns:n1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="TFavoriteAddressesArray">
        <xs:complexContent>
          <xs:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
            <xs:sequence/>
            <xs:attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" n1:arrayType="ns3:TWEBFavotiteAddress[]" xmlns:n1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="TBookAccount3">
        <xs:complexContent>
          <xs:extension base="ns1:TBookAccount2">
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="UserCustomerID" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="urn:TypeWEB" xmlns="urn:TypeWEB">
      <xs:simpleType name="TAccountType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="actNone"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="actWebAccount"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
      <xs:simpleType name="TWEBAccountStatus">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="wasNone"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="wasCreate"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="wasUpdate"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="wasNotUnique"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="wasMoved"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="wasValid"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="wasSuspended"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="urn:TypeOrder" xmlns="urn:TypeOrder">
      <xs:complexType name="TWEBAddress">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="StreetPlace" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="AptBaz" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="Postal" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="CityID" type="xs:int"/>
          <xs:element name="RegionID" type="xs:int"/>
          <xs:element name="CountryID" type="xs:int"/>
          <xs:element name="Longitude" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element name="Latitude" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element name="AddressID" type="xs:int"/>
          <xs:element name="StopTime" type="ns3:TWEBTimeStamp"/>
          <xs:element name="StopOrder" type="xs:int"/>
          <xs:element name="RunOrder" type="xs:int"/>
          <xs:element name="StopPass" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="TWEBTimeStamp">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Year" type="xs:int"/>
          <xs:element name="Month" type="xs:int"/>
          <xs:element name="Day" type="xs:int"/>
          <xs:element name="Hour" type="xs:int"/>
          <xs:element name="Minute" type="xs:int"/>
          <xs:element name="Second" type="xs:int"/>
          <xs:element name="Fractions" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="TWEBFavotiteAddress">
        <xs:complexContent>
          <xs:extension base="ns3:TWEBAddress">
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="AddressAlias" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="TExceptionsArray">
        <xs:complexContent>
          <xs:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
            <xs:sequence/>
            <xs:attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" n1:arrayType="ns3:TException[]" xmlns:n1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="TException">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="ExID" type="xs:int"/>
          <xs:element name="ExName" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="urn:StaticDataIntf" xmlns="urn:StaticDataIntf">
      <xs:complexType name="TVehicleTypeArray">
        <xs:complexContent>
          <xs:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
            <xs:sequence/>
            <xs:attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" n1:arrayType="ns4:TVehicleTypeItem[]" xmlns:n1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="TVehicleTypeItem">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="Capacity" type="xs:int"/>
          <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:int"/>
          <xs:element name="isDefault" type="xs:boolean"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="SaveAccount0Request">
    <part name="Login" type="xs:string"/>
    <part name="Password" type="xs:string"/>
    <part name="Account" type="ns1:TBookAccount"/>
  </message>
  <message name="SaveAccount0Response">
    <part name="return" type="xs:int"/>
  </message>
  <message name="GetWEBAccount1Request">
    <part name="Login" type="xs:string"/>
    <part name="Password" type="xs:string"/>
    <part name="CompanyID" type="xs:int"/>
    <part name="WEBAccountID" type="xs:string"/>
    <part name="WEBPassword" type="xs:string"/>
  </message>
  <message name="GetWEBAccount1Response">
    <part name="return" type="ns1:TBookAccount"/>
  </message>
  <message name="SaveAccount22Request">
    <part name="Login" type="xs:string"/>
    <part name="Password" type="xs:string"/>
    <part name="Account" type="ns1:TBookAccount2"/>
  </message>
  <message name="SaveAccount22Response">
    <part name="return" type="xs:int"/>
  </message>
  <message name="GetWEBAccount23Request">
    <part name="Login" type="xs:string"/>
    <part name="Password" type="xs:string"/>
    <part name="CompanyID" type="xs:int"/>
    <part name="WEBAccountID" type="xs:string"/>
    <part name="WEBPassword" type="xs:string"/>
  </message>
  <message name="GetWEBAccount23Response">
    <part name="return" type="ns1:TBookAccount2"/>
  </message>
  <message name="ChangeAccountLogin4Request">
    <part name="Login" type="xs:string"/>
    <part name="Password" type="xs:string"/>
    <part name="OldUserLogin" type="xs:string"/>
    <part name="OldUserPassword" type="xs:string"/>
    <part name="NewUserLogin" type="xs:string"/>
    <part name="NewUserPassword" type="xs:string"/>
  </message>
  <message name="ChangeAccountLogin4Response">
    <part name="return" type="xs:int"/>
  </message>
  <message name="SaveAccount35Request">
    <part name="Login" type="xs:string"/>
    <part name="Password" type="xs:string"/>
    <part name="Account" type="ns1:TBookAccount3"/>
  </message>
  <message name="SaveAccount35Response">
    <part name="return" type="xs:int"/>
  </message>
  <message name="GetWEBAccount36Request">
    <part name="Login" type="xs:string"/>
    <part name="Password" type="xs:string"/>
    <part name="CompanyID" type="xs:int"/>
    <part name="WEBAccountID" type="xs:string"/>
    <part name="WEBPassword" type="xs:string"/>
  </message>
  <message name="GetWEBAccount36Response">
    <part name="return" type="ns1:TBookAccount3"/>
  </message>
  <portType name="IWebAccount3">
    <operation name="SaveAccount">
      <input message="tns:SaveAccount0Request"/>
      <output message="tns:SaveAccount0Response"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="GetWEBAccount">
      <input message="tns:GetWEBAccount1Request"/>
      <output message="tns:GetWEBAccount1Response"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="SaveAccount2">
      <input message="tns:SaveAccount22Request"/>
      <output message="tns:SaveAccount22Response"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="GetWEBAccount2">
      <input message="tns:GetWEBAccount23Request"/>
      <output message="tns:GetWEBAccount23Response"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="ChangeAccountLogin">
      <input message="tns:ChangeAccountLogin4Request"/>
      <output message="tns:ChangeAccountLogin4Response"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="SaveAccount3">
      <input message="tns:SaveAccount35Request"/>
      <output message="tns:SaveAccount35Response"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="GetWEBAccount3">
      <input message="tns:GetWEBAccount36Request"/>
      <output message="tns:GetWEBAccount36Response"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="IWebAccount3binding" type="tns:IWebAccount3">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="SaveAccount">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:WebAccount3Intf-IWebAccount3#SaveAccount" style="rpc"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:WebAccount3Intf-IWebAccount3"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:WebAccount3Intf-IWebAccount3"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="GetWEBAccount">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:WebAccount3Intf-IWebAccount3#GetWEBAccount" style="rpc"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:WebAccount3Intf-IWebAccount3"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:WebAccount3Intf-IWebAccount3"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="SaveAccount2">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:WebAccount3Intf-IWebAccount3#SaveAccount2" style="rpc"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:WebAccount3Intf-IWebAccount3"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:WebAccount3Intf-IWebAccount3"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="GetWEBAccount2">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:WebAccount3Intf-IWebAccount3#GetWEBAccount2" style="rpc"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:WebAccount3Intf-IWebAccount3"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:WebAccount3Intf-IWebAccount3"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="ChangeAccountLogin">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:WebAccount3Intf-IWebAccount3#ChangeAccountLogin" style="rpc"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:WebAccount3Intf-IWebAccount3"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:WebAccount3Intf-IWebAccount3"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="SaveAccount3">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:WebAccount3Intf-IWebAccount3#SaveAccount3" style="rpc"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:WebAccount3Intf-IWebAccount3"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:WebAccount3Intf-IWebAccount3"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="GetWEBAccount3">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:WebAccount3Intf-IWebAccount3#GetWEBAccount3" style="rpc"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:WebAccount3Intf-IWebAccount3"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:WebAccount3Intf-IWebAccount3"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="IWebAccount3service">
    <port name="IWebAccount3Port" binding="tns:IWebAccount3binding">
      <soap:address location="http://184.69.53.74:6928/XDS_IASPI.DLL/soap/IWebAccount3"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

Also here, the **soap location** was **http://duffystaxi.no-ip.info:6928/XDS_IASPI.DLL/soap/IWebAccount3**, had a suggestion to change domain name to ip address, which also returns

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to
>   host in /home/careec1d/public_html/duffytaxi/core/config.php:56 Stack
>   trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('http://184.69.5...', 'urn:WebAccount3...', 1, 0) #1
>   /home/careec1d/public_html/duffytaxi/core/config.php(56):
>   SoapClient->__soapCall('GetWEBAccount3', Array) #2
>   /home/careec1d/public_html/duffytaxi/core/auth.php(17):
>   Client->getAccount('testcorp', 'testcorp') #3
>   /home/careec1d/public_html/duffytaxi/helpers/do_login.php(8):
>   Auth::login(Array) #4
>   /home/careec1d/public_html/duffytaxi/account/login.php(22):
>   require_once('/home/careec1d/...') #5 {main} thrown in
>   /home/careec1d/public_html/duffytaxi/core/config.php on line 56

I added `"stream_context"=> stream_context_create($opt)` to the `$params` array, but the still doesn't solve the problem. 
My PHP version is 5.3

Comment: Error is pretty clear , your production server can't connect to external host , verify firewall or proxy configuration, compare your local php configuration and production with phpinfo maybe missing something

Comment: @Fky thanks for your reply, but how do I do this on cPanel?